# Set web service url from a file

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-ce

I have a web service and is consumed from a Windows CE application. Currently I hard coded the URL by adding it as web reference. Is there any way I can supply the URL separately, so that I don't have to recompile the solution when I change the URL?

Comment: You can simply change the endpoint url. Say if you had some service object `svc` then you can do `svc.Url = "http://..."`.

Comment: You can add an app.config by adding a property in VS, or you could open a file to read, but you would then need to already know where the file will but unless you set up some kind of config file anyways.

Comment: I will deploy the application and later if the url changes i do not want to recompile and redeploy again. If I have a file to store the url, then i just need to modify the new url in the file!!

Comment: @iMortalitySX I doubt we have app.config in windows ce solution

Comment: I'm just saying you can make one, or create some type of config file for you application to read.  Or you could add a registry entry if you are so inclined, but you will need to ensure it is created during install...

Comment: @iMortalitySX That makes sense.. Let me try it out, thanks..

Comment: See [Ways to Customize your ASMX Client Proxy](http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2008/06/05/ways-to-customize-your-asmx-client-proxy/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is:
1.  Create your webservice reference in a project
2. change setting to be "dynamic url"
3. store your url in a file.
4. Change reference.cs file to use your url.
done.
for step by step instruction you can follow [this code project article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12317/How-to-make-your-Web-Reference-proxy-URL-dynamic)

Answer (score 0):

thanks to RAS for his answer,
if you set your desired URL in  yourprojectname.exe.config which is Located in Debug folder, you can use that service any where without need to reCompile. so I complete dear RAS's answer:

1. Create your webservice reference with a special URL, in your project (consider your project name is XYZ)
2. change setting of your webSercive to be "dynamic url"
3. compile your project.
4. replace your desired URL in XYZ.exe.config with old special URL, any where and any time.